# Do normal tears do increased damage with Chemical Peel?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

The Chemical Peel item's text said "DMG UP" and it changed my tears to blood tears, but it didn't change the tear icon.  Every so often, I shoot a normal tear.  Do only the blood tears get the increased damage bonus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every other shot you fire deals increased damage with Chemical Peel.